# Rewrite URL doesn't work in .htaccess file

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have problem using .htaccess to rewrite some of the friendly URL.

The root URL is http://www.example.com/my/

The working call url is http://www.example.com/my/Post.php?id=2

Both .htaccess file and Post.php are located in the sub-directory http://www.example.com/my/

But I  wanted it to be like the following:
http://www.example.com/my/job/kuantan/?id=2

**The .htaccess configuration as below:**

```
DirectoryIndex index.php

Options All -Indexes

#ErrorDocument 404 /404.php

Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.example.com$ [NC]

RewriteRule ^job/kuantan/([0-9]+)  /Post.php?id=$1 [L,QSA, NC]
```

BUT, once i deployed the above .htaccess configuration file, it prompted 500 internal error message as well.

Is something missing or wrong in the .htaccess configuration? Please advice and really appreciated if someone there could give a hand. Thanks.

Comment: Your rule is commented out, try removing `#` from `#RewriteRule ^job/kuantan/([0-9]+)  /Post.php?id=$1 [L,QSA, NC]`

Comment: Hi IkoTiskashi , sorry i have removed the # comment. It didn't work either. Please advice!

Answer (score 0):

You can have this code in `/my/.htaccess`:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /my/

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /Post\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ job/kuantan [R=302,L,NE]

RewriteRule ^job/kuantan/?$ Post.php [L,NC]
```

Query String is automatically carried over so there is no need to capture it in rule.

Comment: Thanks anubhava for the answer. I have followed your instruction and tried, but it failed. Instead i got '404 Not Found' -> The requested URL /my/job/kuantan/Post.php was not found on this server.   Please advice!

Comment: Also, shouldn't I need a "([0-9]+)"   AND  "Post.php?id=$1"  on the RewriteRule you've given? Please advice!

Comment: Hi Anubhava, thanks for the update. I have followed your updated guideline but it failed as well. Instead, i got this '404 Not Found - The requested URL /my/Post was not found on this server.' Please advice. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should just need a single rule:

```
RewriteRule ^/my/job/kuantan/$ /my/Post.php
```

The query string is carried over by default.

Comment: Hi bobdye, thanks for the replied. Btw, i did the same as you instructed. But it failed again.  -> RewriteRule ^/my/job/kuantan/$ /my/OrangSini_JobPosting.php [L,NC]      With 404 Not Found error message. Please advice.

Comment: Are you sure that (1) http://example.com/my/OrangSini_JobPosting.php exists? and (2) there is no other RewriteRule changing it before or after this rule.

Comment: Hi bobdye, sorry for the wrong file name mentioned (that's another sample test). Indeed, the http://example.com/my/Post.php existed. Pls advice. cheers

Comment: Hmm, strange. Just to be sure, is there really a slash at the end of the first URL? The rule will match http://example.com/my/job/kuantan/?id=2 but not http://example.com/my/job/kuantan?id=2.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that .htaccess and Post.php are located in the sub-directory `/my/`:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
Options All -Indexes
#ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.example.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^job/kuantan/([0-9]+)$  Post.php?id=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

Remove all spaces between `[]`. Change `/Post.php?id=1` to `Post.php?id=$1`.

Comment: Hi IkoTikashi, thanks for the promptly answer. Indeed, both the .htaccess file and Post.php are located in the sub-directory http://www.example.com/my/  .. As followed your guideline,  it's still failed and got this error message of "404 NOT Found - The requested URL /my/job/kuantan/ was not found on this server." . In addition, the url that entered was "http://www.example.com/my/job/kuantan/?id=8" ... Hmm.. weird and i have no idea what's gone wrong here. Please advice.

Comment: If you don't need it comment out `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.example.com$ [NC]`, also make sure that `mod_rewrite` is actually installed.

Comment: Hi IkoTiskashi, thanks for the replied. Indeed, i have commented out the "RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.example.com$ [NC]" and    mod_rewrite is installed default by the server according to the system admin. Please advice. Cheers

Comment: Yes, i have checked with the server administrator and everything is fine.